# Enyo's DragAvatar

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, enyo

I sort of copied the example code from http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.DragAvatar into a jsfiddle to start and test it out.. Now the dragAvatar won't even show up, I have no clue why not. If I put the image outside de dragavatar, it shows up so it's not the image url...

http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/qsSCU/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "App",
    handlers: {
        ondrag: "drag",
        ondragfinish: "dragFinish",
    },
    components: [
        {name:"dragAvatar", kind:"enyo.DragAvatar", showing:true, components: [
            {kind:'enyo.Image', src:'http://s9.postimage.org/h3t5cbidn/enyo_icon.jpg'}]
        }
    ],
    drag: function(inSender, inEvent) {
        this.$.dragAvatar.drag(inEvent);
    },
    dragFinish: function(inSender, inEvent) {
        //this.$.dragAvatar.hide();
    }           
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `'showing: true'` statement in the kind declaration.  DragAvatar isn't rendered until the first drag event so there's nothing to show.  However, when it does go to show the avatar then it sees that the showing is already set to true and doesn't, in fact, show it.  If you remove the line (and uncomment the call to `hide()`) then you'll see the avatar appear when you drag on the Result panel.